# ListboxItem with button for Android using MVVM Light

Tags: android, mvvm-light

I have a working solution for a universal app using MVVM Light.
It looks somehting like this:

```
                <Grid x:Name="grdInfo">
                    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding TheEntries}">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding TheInfo}" />
                                    <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Start Action" 
                                  Command="{Binding DataContext.TheActionCommand, ElementName=grdInfo}" 
                                CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
                </Grid>
```

The code behind looks something like this:

```
    RelayCommand<SomeItemType> rC = new RelayCommand<SomeItemTyp>(HandleThis);

    private void HandleThis(SomeItemType TheItem) {
        ...
    }
```

How (if even possible) can this be done with Android (further using MVVM Light)

Comment: @Derek: Yes - I forgot to mention - I'm using Xamarin.
So I code in C#.

Comment: If you want more detail let me know, I wasn't sure if you meant binding in general or for a collection.

Comment: To clarify - I'm new to Android - my knowledge is "basic binding" - commands, text and so on forms. My problem is - how to bind a command to a list item in a way that the command handler gets the originating object (the one list element on which the button was clicked)

Answer (score 0):

On Android if you're not using some sort of binding you'll do it [manually](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/working_with_listviews_and_adapters/part_2_-_populating_a_listview_with_data/).

update:

It seems MvvmLight has extension methods for [bindings](http://blog.galasoft.ch/posts/2014/05/mvvm-light-v4-4-with-xamarin-android-support/), [extension method source](http://gist.github.com/dbeattie71/532f78ca83482b89dcc7):

```
this.AddBinding(
            () => Vm.Hello,
            () => MyButton.Text);

        MyButton.AddCommand(
            "Click",
            Vm.IncrementCommand);
```

More advanced bindings:

Use the bindings from MvvmCross: [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=cFsuCN-9MdQ), [code](https://github.com/MvvmCross/NPlus1DaysOfMvvmCross/tree/master/N-30-ChimpCrossLight)

Use [Xamarin.Forms](http://xamarin.com/forms), binding support is built in, using code or XAML.

Make your own, see [QuickCross](https://github.com/MacawNL/QuickCross), it does simple binding.

Comment: Since you mention different framework than the one (MVVMLight) I use - does this mean MVVMLight doesn't support what I'm asking for?

Comment: I'm incorrect, I didn't realize Laurent added something for this.  http://blog.galasoft.ch/posts/2014/05/mvvm-light-v4-4-with-xamarin-android-support/